# live view is not working on surface view

Tags: android, surfaceview

how to enable live camera view using surface view

Im using;

```
mCamera = Camera.open();

surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use something called a Camera Preview. This will show what the camera sees to the use and you can then use API's to control the camera actions.

here is a very nice tutorial for this from the official developer docs: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#custom-camera